# How to refresh site if $_SESSION variable has changed

Tags: php, mysql, session, refresh

I'm writing in my $_SESSION variable from a database, when i clicked a link.

```
public function getProjectById($id){
  $query="SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id=\"$id\"";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  $num=mysql_numrows($result);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $_SESSION['projectid'] = $row->id;
    $_SESSION['projecttitle'] = $row->title;
    $_SESSION['projectinfo'] = $row->info;
    $_SESSION['projecttext'] = $row->text;
    $_SESSION['projectcategory'] = $row->category;
  }
}
```

Now my variable is overwritten and I want to show these variables in my index.php like this:

```
<div id="textContent">
   <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['projecttext']) && !empty($_SESSION['projecttext'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['projecttext'];
    }else {
        echo 'No text';
    }
?></div>
```

But of course, my page will not refresh automatically. How can I do that?

Edit: calling code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".sublink", function(){
    var subsite = $(this).data('subsite');
    var category = $(this).data('category');
    var title = $(this).data('title');
    var info = category + "/" + title;
    var lower = info.toLowerCase();
    var nospaces = lower.split(' ').join('');
    $('#imageContent').load('php/getImages.php?info='+nospaces);
    $('#textContent').load('php/getProjectById.php?id='+subsite);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with "Now my variable is overwritten" ? when does that happen?

Comment: I mean it is replaced by my new data from the database. This happens when I click on my link. But it is not refreshing the graphical layout. The text will not change

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this (javascript replacing your html code already visible to the user, or used to refresh the complete page), but I guess your function-call is triggered by an onclick (calling a specific php-page) you will probably do best with a [Meta Refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Reloading the whole page.
Please take note, this is considered unfancy nowadays ;-)

Edit: like this:

```
public function getProjectById($id){
  $query="SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id=\"$id\"";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  $num=mysql_numrows($result);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $_SESSION['projectid'] = $row->id;
    $_SESSION['projecttitle'] = $row->title;
    $_SESSION['projectinfo'] = $row->info;
    $_SESSION['projecttext'] = $row->text;
    $_SESSION['projectcategory'] = $row->category;
  }
// everything done here, do a meta refresh here
?> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'"> <?php
// worse alternative using .. echo("<meta....
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it via php? Best would be after I read my result (after the while loop). And yes my link calls the php onclick from javascript.

Comment: yep, see edit. Simply replace example.com vith your url (index.php or something)

Comment: Hmm there comes no effect with that :7

Comment: I had a content="5... there earlier, meaning it takes 5 seconds to reload (edited to 0 to do it at an instant). But maybe still not working. Could you edit your calling code into your post? the pos where you have the onclick